# How can i access window object in the angular5 in the way we do this " @ViewChild('fileInput') inputEl: ElementRef" for DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular-universal

I tried to search already asked questions related to my issue, but the solutions could not help.

## Angular_5=>frontend(with angular universal)

## Nodejs=>Backend

I want to do the **scrolling effect in typescript something** like in the code snippet with Jquery code but not with "`jquery`" module.
My concern is to do this as per `angular5` guidelines, keeping in mind the server side rendering(angular universal).

```
onWindowScroll(event){ 
    if(window.scrollY >=350){
        console.log("some_value"+window.scrollY);
        $('.evaluate-h1').addClass('animated fadeInUp')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm install smoothscroll-polyfill --save`

then add it to your `polyfill.ts` file:

```
/**
 * Polyfill for smooth scrollIntoView()
 */
require('smoothscroll-polyfill').polyfill();
```

afterwards you can use vanilla javascript `.scrollIntoView()` to scroll to your ElementRef:

```
const element:HTMLElement = this.document.getElementById(this.slug);

if(element) element.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth', 
    block: 'start' 
});
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but it will solve only the window scroll, i needed the way to access window object for more generic control over window object.